# cannot access protected member ... without a python subclass of 

Tags: asp.net, ironpython

bt_volver is a System.Web.UI.webcontrols.button and it's just a code it used to work fine in 2.0

```
IronPython 2.6.911.0 in ASP.NET webforms 
Visual Studio 2008 Professional 9.0.30729.1 SP

 cannot access protected member
 bt_volver without a python subclass of
 abmlocalidades_aspx

  Error de código fuente: 

  Línea 7:          else: bt_volver.Visible = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known change - you should use reflection to access protected and private members.

```
something.GetType().GetField("bt_volver", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

Or you can try `ipy.exe -X:PrivateBinding` switch.